# Trying to use angular brackets

Tags: html, tags, windows-11

When writing code how do I get angular brackets on windows 11? I tried YouTubing it and also looking it up on Google. I have been stuck trying to figure this out and haven’t been able to.

Comment: Are you referring to the < and > characters?  Most standard English-layout keyboards have those under Shift + , and Shift + . depending on which you need.

Comment: He might be referring to the mathematic symbols, e.g., https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/shortcut-for-angle-bracket-symbol/e6d18bd6-85aa-4ce4-bdd6-a505d416cedd. It’s not entirely clear from the question.